# How can I access custom HttpRequest Headers from a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, request, portable-class-library

I have a client facing UI, and backend REST API, and a C# portable class library as a wrapper for the client when calling into the REST API.

When a user clicks on the UI, I want to be able to capture that users IP address in the PCL, and pass it through to the REST api seamlessly as part of each HttpRequestMessage, without the UI application needing to provide it.

I have the ability in the full framework; but I'm not clear how to pull it off for a PCL.

The full framework version of the class I want to use to capture the users IP address is below; but as soon as I pull it over to the PCL, the IPAddress and HttpRequest classes are not available; basically the core of what I need.

.NET Code ::

```
public static string GetRemoteIpAddress(HttpRequest request)
        {
            // Added this check because when a web site starts up, there is a brief period of time while inside the
            // global.application_start method where request isn't yet initialized and is an exception.
            if (request == null || request is HttpException) return "0.0.0.0";

            //algorithm:
            //1. Check X-Forwarded-For header for non-local IP address
            //2. If none exists from 1, check Toluna-NS-Forwarded-For header for non-local IP address
            //3. If none exists from 2, check Remote-Addr header
            //4. If none exists from 3, return UserHostAddress

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parseIpAddressCsvList(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP])))
            {
                return parseIpAddressCsvList(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP]);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parseIpAddressCsvList(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR])))
            {
                return parseIpAddressCsvList(request.ServerVariables[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR]);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ServerVariables[NS_FORWARD_FOR_KEY]) &&
                isIPAddress(request.ServerVariables[NS_FORWARD_FOR_KEY]))
            {
                return request.ServerVariables[NS_FORWARD_FOR_KEY];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ServerVariables[REMOTE_ADDR]) &&
                isIPAddress(request.ServerVariables[REMOTE_ADDR]))
            {
                return request.ServerVariables[REMOTE_ADDR];
            }

            return request.UserHostAddress;
        }

        private static string parseIpAddressCsvList(string csvList)
        {
            string[] addresses = csvList.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');


            return addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => !a.StartsWith("10.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                !a.StartsWith("192.168.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                isIPAddress(a));
        }


        private static bool isIPAddress(string ipAddress)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress))
                return false;


            IPAddress dummy;
            return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out dummy);
        }
```

Comment: In PCL it is common to use `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http`. It has `DefaultRequestHeaders` for passing headers.

Comment: Adding headers to the DefaultRequestHeaders is not ideal since the value could change from request to request. I need to try and capture the headers from the users request so I can add it to the HttpRequestMessage headers when calling into the REST API.

Comment: You can use new instance of `HttpClient` for each request and set different header values

Comment: With `HttpRequestMessage`you can do something like this: `httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage
                            {
                                Method = HttpMethod.Delete,
                                RequestUri = requestUri,
                                Content = ...
                            }, cancellationToken);`